# String.xml or Constants class

Tags: android, android-xml

What is better approach of the following in designing an Android app

1. To place all the String constants in `res/values/Strings.xml`
   or
2. Create a class like `Constant.java` where all Strings are `public static final`?

Choosing which one of them is more efficient?

Comment: I believe they are processed faster in strings.xml
see-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475599/defining-strings-in-res-values-string-xml

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I imagine a constants class would be more efficient.

However, speed shouldn't really be an issue in either case. I would recommend organizing based on what makes sense.

**Constants class**

Put strings constants that will be used internally, like database column names or other keys.

**strings.xml**

Put strings that are displayed for the user. This way you can take advantage of localization, etc.