# Annoying default formatting

Tags: android, xml

I am working on a simple android application in eclipse IDE and I got a little yellow icon on the left hand side of a line of xml code that looks like a light bulb with an exclamation mark beside it. When I hovered over, it says "[I18N] Hardcoded string "input..., should use @string resource input". The running and debug was successful but I just want to get rid of it as I find it annoying. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The right way:**

Move all your strings into resource files, as suggested, and reference them in your views like so: `@string/mystringname`

**The "other" way:**

Turn off Lint warnings in Eclipse in `Window/Preferences/Android/Lint Error Checking`

[image]

Both ways will remove that annoying triangle :)

Comment: The second suggestion helped out big time, all the warnings have now disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

If it's annoying, there is a reason. You totally should use @string resources instead of your hardcoded strings. All you have to do is to put your string in res/values/strings.xml and reference it in your layout via @string/my_string_id_here.

This is extremely useful for multi language support, or for plurals strings.

You can learn more [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html).

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @AnneJones: More generally, these are Lint warnings, pointing out things that are syntactically valid but are unlikely to be right answer.

Answer (score 0):

This warning is there because hardcoding strings into the android app's Java source code is not recommended.  It will compile fine - but [Android Lint](http://tools.android.com/tips/lint) will complain about it, so that's why it's a "warning" and not an "error". Generally, it is preferable to define them in the separate "string.xml" file.

If you want to know why, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4475599/defining-strings-in-res-values-string-xml).
For an example, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8743349/hardcoded-string-row-three-should-use-string-resource).
You should also take a look at the official documentation for [string resources](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html).